# Openvpn quit unexpected after upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, openvpn, radius

My openvpn quits unexpectedly since I upgraded my ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04LTS

Below is the content of the log file of openvpn.

```
Wed Mar  1 13:46:33 2017 username/123.123.123.123:56729 WARNING: Failed running command (--client-connect): external program exited with error status: 254
Mar  1 13:46:33 2017 username/123.123.123.123:56729 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Wed Mar  1 13:46:33 2017 username/123.123.123.123:56729 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Wed Mar  1 13:46:33 2017 username/123.123.123.123:56729 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Wed Mar  1 13:46:36 2017 username/123.123.123.123:56729 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Wed Mar  1 13:46:42 2017 :55522 TLS: 123.123.123.123Initial packet from [AF_INET]123.123.123.123:55522, sid=1272ece9 72edde04
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 RADIUS-PLUGIN: FOREGROUND THREAD: New user.
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 RADIUS-PLUGIN: No attributes Acct Interim Interval or bad length.
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 RADIUS-PLUGIN: Client config file was not written, overwriteccfiles is false
.Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 RADIUS-PLUGIN: FOREGROUND THREAD: Add user to map.
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=0
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 TLS: Username/Password authentication succeeded for username 'username' [CN SET]
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 123.123.123.123:55522 [username] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]123.123.123.123:55522
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.so/PLUGIN_CLIENT_DISCONNECT status=0
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 openvpn_execve: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 Exiting due to fatal error
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 /sbin/ip route del 10.25.38.0/24
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 openvpn_execve: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
Wed Mar  1 13:46:43 2017 username/123.123.123.123:55522 Exiting due to fatal error
```

I don't know why this appears.

```
openvpn_execve: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
```

and cause my openvpn quit
`LIMITNPROC=10 in /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`  are already comment out.

Comment: Did you find a solution? - same problem here

Comment: @RomanGaufman edit /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service file, and find out **LimitNPROC** line, and remove the line. After that restart your openvpn.

Comment: @JohnsonGoey I ran into this problem when trying to start OpenVPN client instance in a LXD container. Commenting out LimitNPROC=10 fixed it. Could, you, please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known problem in the systemd `.service` file of the OpenVPN.

More exactly, systemd limits the processes of the openvpn in 10 with the `LimitNProc=10` setting in `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` file. Remove this line, and it will work.

[Some sources](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1631104) state on the internet, that growing this value to 100 will be enough. On my experiments, it didn't work - note also, already 10 should be enough, because OpenVPN practically never forks so many processes. It is probably some systemd bug.

Note also, it is better practice to create a copy of the `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` and to modify that config file. On this way, it will override the original settings.

After modifying systemd service files, a `systemctl daemon-reload` should be given to re-load them (without reboot).

Comment: Even better is to create a drop-in file, using `systemctl edit openvpn@`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Drop-in_files

Comment: @Thomas Right, thanks! Although I do not trust systemd so much. ;-)

Comment: This is weird, when an openvpn client is trying to connect the `tls-verify` command fails to run because of the `LimitNPROC` setting. The default in the latest ubuntu is `LimitNPROC=100` and my `tls-verify` script certainly does not use 100 processes. I figured out empirically that `LimitNPROC=191` still does not work and `LimitNPROC=192` works. I don't know why it needs to be so high.

Comment: @PaulTobias I does not start even 10 processes, not 192. I think it is systemd bug, so I entirely removed the NPROC setting.